# which widget is used to show color similar to color palette gtk3

Tags: python, c, gtk, gtk3

im creating gui application using gtk3 C, where user will enter RGB value, i need to save that color and display it for later use, like color palette, default colorchoose widget is not suitable for my application

what exactly i want is available in gtk3-widget-factory as show in image below, but i can't find the widget name

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the source code of the widget used on gtk3-widget-factory :

```
static void
populate_colors (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  struct { const gchar *name; const gchar *color; const gchar *title; } colors[] = {
    { "2.5", "#C8828C", "Red" },
    { "5", "#C98286", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#C9827F", NULL },
    { "10", "#C98376", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#C8856D", "Red/Yellow" },
    { "5", "#C58764", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#C1895E", NULL },
    { "10", "#BB8C56", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#B58F4F", "Yellow" },
    { "5", "#AD924B", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#A79548", NULL },
    { "10", "#A09749", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#979A4E", "Yellow/Green" },
    { "5", "#8D9C55", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#7F9F62", NULL },
    { "10", "#73A06E", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#65A27C", "Green" },
    { "5", "#5CA386", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#57A38D", NULL },
    { "10", "#52A394", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#4EA39A", "Green/Blue" },
    { "5", "#49A3A2", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#46A2AA", NULL },
    { "10", "#46A1B1", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#49A0B8", "Blue" },
    { "5", "#529EBD", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#5D9CC1", NULL },
    { "10", "#689AC3", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#7597C5", "Blue/Purple" },
    { "5", "#8095C6", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#8D91C6", NULL },
    { "10", "#988EC4", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#A08CC1", "Purple" },
    { "5", "#A88ABD", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#B187B6", NULL },
    { "10", "#B786B0", NULL },
    { "2.5", "#BC84A9", "Purple/Red" },
    { "5", "#C183A0", NULL },
    { "7.5", "#C48299", NULL },
    { "10", "#C68292", NULL }
  };
  gint i;
  GtkWidget *row, *box, *label, *swatch;
  GdkRGBA rgba;

  gtk_list_box_set_header_func (GTK_LIST_BOX (widget), update_title_header, NULL, NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < G_N_ELEMENTS (colors); i++)
    {
      row = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 20);
      label = gtk_label_new (colors[i].name);
      g_object_set (label,
                    "halign", GTK_ALIGN_START,
                    "valign", GTK_ALIGN_CENTER,
                    "margin", 6,
                    "xalign", 0.0,
                    NULL);
      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (row), label, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      gdk_rgba_parse (&rgba, colors[i].color);
      swatch = g_object_new (g_type_from_name ("GtkColorSwatch"),
                             "rgba", &rgba,
                             "selectable", FALSE,
                             "halign", GTK_ALIGN_END,
                             "valign", GTK_ALIGN_CENTER,
                             "margin", 6,
                             "height-request", 24,
                             NULL);
      box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), swatch);
      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (row), box, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
      gtk_widget_show_all (row);
      gtk_list_box_insert (GTK_LIST_BOX (widget), row, -1);
      row = gtk_widget_get_parent (row);
      gtk_list_box_row_set_activatable (GTK_LIST_BOX_ROW (row), FALSE);
      if (colors[i].title)
        g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (row), "title", (gpointer)colors[i].title);
    }

  gtk_list_box_invalidate_headers (GTK_LIST_BOX (widget));
}
```

I suggest you go visit their github : [Widget factory GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk/tree/master/demos/widget-factory)

Answer (score 2):

It's GtkColorSwatch, which is not available publically, unfortunatelly. However, due to GObject's run-time type system, it's possible to create those widgets.

```py
import gi
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

GObject.type_from_name("GtkColorSwatch") # 1

Gtk.ColorChooserDialog() # 2
GObject.type_from_name("GtkColorSwatch") # 3
```

`Line 1` fails, because GObject doesn't know this type yet. `Line 2` creates GtkColorChooserDialog, which has `GtkColorSwatch's`. A side-effect of this creation is that `GTK_TYPE_COLOR_SWATCH` gets registered in GObject type system and that's why  `line 3` succeeds.